# Custom module, overriding functionality in community extension

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, module

So, I am trying to override a Gallery module I've downloaded and add some fields to the admin form, which would help me to include more options to the frontend.

The module I've downloaded is [Image Gallery with categories](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/image-gallery-with-categories.html) or SAG_Gallery to be precise.

One of the files I am currently interested with is located in `/app/code/community/Sag/Gallery/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Tab/Form.php`.

So I created a sample module and added it to `/etc/modules` named `AcmeDemo`, so now I have `/etc/modules/AcmeDemo.xml`.

In there I've added the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acme_Demo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depend>
                <Sag_Gallery />
            </depend>
        </Acme_Demo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I've also created the path, as follows: `/app/code/local/Acme/Demo`. The module is loaded succesfully as I was able to confirm it by looking at my admin panel in "Advanced" options, it's there.

Then I created few directories to mimic the original path, as follows:

```
/app/code/local/Acme/Demo/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Tab
```

and in there I've created the file `Form.php` with the following code (it's an example, I'm trying to "kill" the form, to ensure my code works)

```
class Bogara_Gallery_Block_Adminhtml_Category_Edit_Tab_Form extends Sag_Gallery_Block_Adminhtml_Category_Edit_Tab_Form {

    protected function _prepareForm() {
        exit;
    }

}
```

I've added the following configuration in `/app/code/local/Acme/Demo/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acme_Demo>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Acme_Demo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <acme_demo>
                <class>Acme_Demo_Block</class>
            </acme_demo>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <category_edit_tab_form>Acme_Demo_Block_Adminhtml_Category_Edit_Tab_Form</category_edit_tab_form>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

which appears to be wrong, since the original `Form.php` is still being executed. Probably is some silly mistake, or something that I've missed.

Any kind of advice/help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should be different:

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
        <category_edit_tab_form>Acme_Demo_Block_Adminhtml_Category_Edit_Tab_Form</category_edit_tab_form>
    </rewrite>
<adminhtml>
```

look in the file `app/code/community/Sag/Gallery/etc/config.xml` and search for a tag named `<blocks>`.
You should find something like this:

```
<blocks>
    <sag_gallery><!-- this may be different, but it's what you need -->
        <class>Sag_Gallery_Block</class>
    </sag_gallery>
</blocks>
```

get the tag name I marked above with a comment, and add this to your module's config instead of `<adminhtml>....`

```
<sag_gallery>
    <rewrite>
        <adminhtml_category_edit_tab_form>Acme_Demo_Block_Adminhtml_Category_Edit_Tab_Form</adminhtml_category_edit_tab_form>
    </rewrite>
</sag_gallery>
```

Comment: Marius, always very good explanation! )

Comment: @Marius what should I right in place of <adminhtml_category_edit_tab_form> , if I want to rewrite any custom extension (I want to add new tab to aw_blog extension).

Comment: It depends from extension to extension. I have no idea how aw_blog is configured.